# What is the best approach for creating a reusable view with a custom layout in Titanium?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to create a custom view that will allow for "pluggable" layout routines.  Ideally, I like to setup the view so that when a child view is added it is automatically sized relative to the parent and other siblings.

What is the correct way to do this in Titanium?  Not being a "true" Object Oriented language, overriding the "add()" method sounds like a bad idea.  Is there some kind of "layout" event I can register for?  Am I thinking about this the wrong way?  Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'll do what you're looking for, but to achieve reusable OO style functionality with Appcelerator I've used the [Helium library](https://github.com/kwhinnery/Helium) written by Kevin Whinnery of Appcelerator. It allows you to write factory functions, essentially constructors, where things you'd like to automate, like resizing to a parent view, can be encapsulated for re-use. You can make use of the configuration object passed to the constructor to alter the layout you give to your constructed view, thus making it pluggable.

Comment: I've tried to look into the Helium Library a few times but find it over kill.  Besides, what I really would like to understand is the mechanics of doing it "by hand" first before I start to look at a framework to make it easier.  This kind of fundamental Object Oriented design should be possible I would imagine.  If its not, I'd like to understand the specifics of why.